# Optimized code two get uncommon charaters in two strings( following the flames game rule)

Tags: java, android, optimization

My Interviewer asked me to write optimized code for FLAMES Game

The rules of games are following.

1-Take two names (i.e. - 'naveen' and 'tejveer')

2-Compare these two string to get uncommon characters like

na**vee**n

t**e**j**ve**er

bold characters are common in both and should be removed

**NOTE**- If there is one character occurs two times in string1 and same character occurs 3 times in another string then there is two characters treated as common and one as uncommon

3-Remove the common characters (three common characters in this example 'e', 'v' , 'e')

4-Get the count of the characters that are left (after removing common characters 7 characters left and these are - n , a , n , t , e , j , r.)

I have write these two functions.
//This is normal function (without two much optimization)

```
private static void flames2(String name1 , String name2){
    int n1Length = name1.length();
    int n2Length = name2.length();
    StringBuilder target;
    StringBuilder player;
    int oCounter;
    int iCounter;
    if(n1Length > n2Length){
        player = new StringBuilder(name1);  
        target = new StringBuilder(name2);

        oCounter = n1Length;
        iCounter = n2Length;
    }else{
        player = new StringBuilder(name2);  
        target = new StringBuilder(name1);  
        oCounter = n2Length;
        iCounter = n1Length;
    }

    int matches = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i< oCounter ; i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < iCounter ; j++){
            if(player.charAt(i) ==  target.charAt(j)){
                char chTemp = target.charAt(j);
                target.setCharAt(j , target.charAt(iCounter-1));
                target.setCharAt(iCounter-1 , chTemp);
                iCounter--;
                matches++;
                break;
            }       
        }   
    }
    int unmatchedChars = name1.length()+name2.length()-2*matches;
    System.out.println("result "+unmatchedChars);
}
```

and then He told me to do this problem by using one for loop and I tried this function which is somewhat optimized.

```
private static void flames3(String name1 , String name2){
    int n1Length = name1.length();
    int n2Length = name2.length();
    StringBuffer target;
    String player;
    int oCounter;

    if(n1Length < n2Length){
        target = new StringBuffer(name2);
        player = name1;
        oCounter = n1Length;

    }else{
        target = new StringBuffer(name1);   
        player = name2;
        oCounter = n2Length;
    }

    int matches = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< oCounter ; i++){
        int index = target.toString().indexOf(player.charAt(i));
        if(index >= 0){
            target.setCharAt(index,'_');
            matches++;      
        }
    }
    int unmatchedChars = name1.length()+name2.length()-2*matches;
    System.out.println("result "+unmatchedChars);
}
```

But In function flames3 I am using String.IndexOf() which use a for loop to check the character.

In these functions I am just counting the matched characters. 
So there is a way to write more optimized function.

Comment: `Collection.removeAll` ?

Comment: @MohammedAtif. Hello Atif. Thanks for your time . That's why I asked the question. Please write the solution.

Comment: You can simply use String.replace(). Let me know if you still need full solution. @NavinGupta

Comment: @MohammedAtif please write the solution

Comment: @MohammedAtif Just like `indexOf`, `replace` also uses a loop internally.

Comment: yes I know that. and here for replace I used Strinbuider.setCharAt(index) to replace the character

Comment: Yes definitely @Titus, here loops within the function calls are not an issue. But the final code and output will definitely make the difference.

Answer (score -1):

Following thing may work fine in optimised way.

```
 public void flames(String name1, String name2) {

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < name1.length(); i++) {
        list1.add(String.valueOf(name1.charAt(i)));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < name2.length(); i++) {
        list2.add(String.valueOf(name2.charAt(i)));
    }
    List<String> union = new ArrayList<String>(list1);
    union.addAll(list2);
    List<String> intersection = new ArrayList<String>(list1);
    intersection.retainAll(list2);
    union.removeAll(intersection);
    for (String n : union) {
        Log.d("item", n);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time. But in this question If there is one character occurs two times in string1 and same character occurs 3 times in another string then there is two characters treated as common and one as uncommon

Comment: for example in "naveen" there is two 'e' and in "tejveer" there is three "e" so two 'e' matches and one e will be counted as unmathced character

Comment: so the unmatched characters should be 7. but in your example it is 6. One more thing it will take more time to run.